# Hive: Create External Table Fails - No FileSystem for scheme: pxf

Tags: hadoop, hive, external-tables

I've been trying to create external tables from hive to access hdfs.

this is the code:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE yellow_ext
(ip_addr     string,
 unknown1    string,
 unknown2    string,
 tanggal     string,
 unknown3    string,
 http_resp1  string,
 http_resp2  string,
 reffr       string,
 browser     string
 )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
 STORED AS TEXTFILE
 LOCATION 'pxf://phdmaster:50070/access_log_1k_rows2?PROFILE=hive';
```

Then i get the error:

```
FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Got exception: java.io.IOException No FileSystem for scheme: pxf)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

i'm confused, where did i do wrong.. any help would be great!

Thanks!

-efraim-

Comment: PXF is an extensible framework that allows HAWQ to query external system data.